# React Custom Modal Component Problems With Updating Same Component Used Repeatedly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I built a custom Modal.

There is one particular function I would like it to do when opened.  I would like a CSS class to be toggled when this modal is opened/closed.

This works just fine if I only insert this component once in a template. But in my case I am inserting it three times. By using the componentDidMount I insert some JS that should toggle the CSS class. It does not do it for the first or the second modal, it will only do it for the third.

CODE UPDATED!

This is the parent component:

```
import React from "react";
import ModalSmall from "./ModalSmall";
import ModalMedium from "./ModalMedium";
import ModalLarge from "./ModalLarge";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import "./styles.scss";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isModalSmallOpen: false,
      isModalMediumOpen: false,
      isModalLargeOpen: false
    };
  }

  toggleModalSmall = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      isModalSmallOpen: !prev.isModalSmallOpen
    }));
  };

  toggleModalMedium = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      isModalMediumOpen: !prev.isModalMediumOpen
    }));
  };

  toggleModalLarge = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      isModalLargeOpen: !prev.isModalLargeOpen
    }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col">
            <h1>Hello Y'all!</h1>
            <p className="yo-green">My Modal Samples</p>

            <div className="row mt-5">
              <div className="col">
                <button
                  className="btn btn-primary"
                  onClick={this.toggleModalSmall}
                >
                  Modal Small
                </button>
              </div>
              <div className="col">
                <button
                  className="btn btn-primary"
                  onClick={this.toggleModalMedium}
                >
                  Modal Medium
                </button>
              </div>
              <div className="col">
                <button
                  className="btn btn-primary"
                  onClick={this.toggleModalLarge}
                >
                  Modal Large
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <ModalSmall
          modalName="smallModal"
          modalTitle="Small Modal"
          modalBody="This is the small modal!"
          toggleModal={this.toggleModalSmall}
          modalOpen={this.state.isModalSmallOpen}
        />
        <ModalMedium
          modalName="mediumModal"
          modalTitle="Medium Modal"
          modalBody="This is the medium modal!"
          toggleModal={this.toggleModalMedium}
          modalOpen={this.state.isModalMediumOpen}
        />
        <ModalLarge
          modalName="largeModal"
          modalTitle="Large Modal"
          modalBody="This is the LARGE modal!"
          toggleModal={this.toggleModalLarge}
          modalOpen={this.state.isModalLargeOpen}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

One of the in-between components:

```
import React from "react";
import Modal from "./Modal";

const ModalSmall = (props) => {
  return (
    <Modal
      modalName={props.modalName}
      modalTitle={props.modalTitle}
      modalBody={props.modalBody}
      toggleModal={props.toggleModal}
      modalOpen={props.modalOpen}
    />
  );
};

export default ModalSmall;
```

Here is my modal Component:

```
import React from "react";

export default class Modal extends React.Component {
  componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.props.modalOpen) {
      console.log("Open!", this.props.modalOpen);
      document.body.classList.add("drawer-open");
    } else {
      console.log("Closed!", this.props.modalOpen);
      document.body.classList.remove("drawer-open");
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="mymodal" id={this.props.modalName}>
        <div
          onClick={this.props.toggleModal}
          className={`mymodal-overlay ${this.props.modalOpen && "active"}`}
            ></div>
        <div
          className={`mymodal-content d-flex flex-column ${
            this.props.modalOpen && "active"
          }`}
        >
          <header className="p-2 border-bottom d-flex">
            <span
              className="material-icons clickable"
              onClick={this.props.toggleModal}
            >
              close
            </span>
            <div className="flex-grow-1 ml-2">{this.props.modalTitle}</div>
          </header>
          <div className="p-2 flex-grow-1">{this.props.modalBody}</div>
          <footer className="p-2 border-top">&copy; ChidoPrime 2021</footer>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[Working Sample Here with Solution Applied](https://codesandbox.io/s/my-custom-modal-jb8m4?file=/src/Modal.js:0-1253)

UPDATE! -------------

There is a second approach I would like to include, different than the checked answer offered by @sanishJoseph.  In which I add a constructor and declare a state within the modal controller. Without the need of using React.PureComponent. I use preProvs within the componentDidUpdate. Code for the modal follows:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      modalOpen: false
    };
  }


  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.modalOpen === this.props.modalOpen) return;

    if (this.props.modalOpen) {
      console.log("Open!", this.props.modalOpen);
      document.body.classList.add("drawer-open");
    } else {
      console.log("Closed!", this.props.modalOpen);
      document.body.classList.remove("drawer-open");
    }
  }
```

[Second Sample using prevProps without using React.PureComponent](https://codesandbox.io/s/my-custom-modal-second-approach-bh0xu?file=/src/Modal.js)

Comment: Is the class 'modal-open' gets removed every time you close the modal? Can you check the body tag on the developer console?

Comment: @SanishJoseph Yes, I have checked it.  When I open the first or second component using this modal the css class is added and then quickly removed as the code cycles past the other components.  It is on the third component when I see (on the dev tool) that the class is added to the body tag and it stays there.  It then gets removed from the body tag when I close the same (3rd) modal.

Comment: All the 3 modals open up one after the other and all there in view at the same time? Can you add a debugger to your else condition in componentDidUpdate to see if that's getting hit when you open more and more modals.

Comment: @SanishJoseph The modals are not all opened at the same time.  I am able to one one after the other.

Comment: @SanishJoseph The following is what appears on the console based on the console.logs that you see in the code above; in the IF and the ELSE statements the numbers you see is the number of times the part of the script is hit:  Small
index.js:8 Open! true
2index.js:11 Closed! false
index.js:18 Small
4index.js:11 Closed! false
index.js:8 Open! true
6index.js:11 Closed! false
index.js:8 Open! true
3index.js:11 Closed! false

Comment: Can you update your question with screenshot of the console? And add the code which calls this modal logic. Issue could on the parent component. Componentdidupdate gets called multiple times for opening the modal for 1 time?

Comment: @SanishJoseph Yes, that is right.  Componentdidupdate gets called multiple times when opening the modal.  I will add the code for the parent component and a screenshot.

Comment: @SanishJoseph   The update is up.

Comment: @SanishJoseph I've put something together for you to play with on CodeSandbox. You can see it here:  https://codesandbox.io/s/my-custom-modal-jb8m4?file=/src/Modal.js:0-1253

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the biggest mistake is in your Parent component. Your initial state of the page is

```
 this.state = {
          isModalSmallOpen: false,
          isModalMediumOpen: false,
          isModalLargeOpen: false
        }
```

But, when you open a Modal, you are setting your state to one item in the state, rest of the items are going null. Meaning, when you do

```
this.setState({
      isModalSmallOpen: !this.state.isModalSmallOpen
    })
```

You are setting `isModalMediumOpen: null, isModalLargeOpen: null`.

What you should be doing is,

```
this.setState((prev) => ({...prev,
          isModalSmallOpen: !prev.isModalSmallOpen
        }))
```

So all of your states will remain in your state. This change is needed in all the 3 modal opening functions.

**Update :**

Fix is petty easy. All you need to do is add a react.memo if it was a functional component. In your case make your Modal component as a PureComponent.

export default class Modal extends React.PureComponent

> Pure Components in React are the components which do not re-renders
> when the value of state and props has been updated with the same
> values.

https://codesandbox.io/s/my-custom-modal-forked-yg4vo?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I tried your example above.  I am getting the same results as before.   I think I am going to put a Plunkr together and post the link here.

Comment: Can you please update your question with the current Parent component?

Comment: Also wrap your toggleModal... functions in a useCallback to cache it so everytime your parent component renders, you won't get a new instances of those methods, which will also re-render your components.

Comment: I tried what you suggested on your update and it didn't work.  I'm still working on putting together a Plunkr.

Comment: The useCallback didn't work.  I was getting the same results on my local project.   I get errors on the CodeSandbox sample I put together when I use useCallback.   See what you can do.

Comment: No need for that. I have updated my answer. All you need to do is make your Modal component as PureComponent. Now it's working as expected.

Comment: Dude, thank you!   That solution was so simple!  

Comment: I know.. Things will be easy when you get the full code. Without full code it's assumptions most of the time.

Comment: Would you believe the solution above is not working on my the actual app I'm working on?   Unbelievable!

Comment: There must be some difference in the code I assume.

Comment: That must be it.  I'm trying to figure that part out.

Answer (score 0):

The code is a little complex to understand, but I think the main problem is with the logic used to implement it. If I understood correctly you are using the same Component more than once. So, each component executes `componentDidUpdate` method each time that is rerendered.

What this means is that if you are toggling one of your modals in the "parent" component with the methods "toggleModal..." then, the parent render method is executed and it executes each render children method. What happened there is that with your first modal you are adding o removing the body css, with the second you are doing the inverse and with the third, you are adding and removing again.

You have a lot of things to get better there, but the most simple is use the arguments you got in your `componentDidUpdated` method and make sure you only executed your code if the new props changes. This going to solve your problem.